# Javascript Performance for Dynamic Image Resouce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I wrote an HTML page that supposed to switch fast between two pictures.
In the [result](https://visualize.netlify.com/) I can see that the first picture is freezed for about a minute and JUST then they start to flip over fast and nicely. It is as if the first picture is loaded quickly and the second takes more time (they have quite the same size)

1. What can explain this behavior?
2. What should I do to make them flip from the very beginning?

Code:

```
<head>
    <title>Visualize</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var file = "a";
            setInterval(function()
            {
                 $('.canvas').attr("src","images/"+ file +".png");

                 file = flipFile(file);
            }, 290);
        });
        function flipFile(file)
        {
            if(file=="a")
            {
                file="b";
            } 
            else if(file=="b")
            {
                file = "a";
            }

            return file;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="canvas" src="/images/file.png">
    </div>        
</body>
```

Comment: Did you check the size of your second image?. Also have you tried changing the setInterval value?

Comment: one is a relative path, one is rooted, but it sounds like the images just take a while to load, might want to preload or use onload instead of ready.

Comment: Yep, preload the images. Also you can move your JS to the bottom of the `<body>` tag. This way you won't need the `.ready` callback.

Comment: Can you elaborate on preload?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I did

1. Placed `<img>` tag for each picture I want to deal with *(with Display:None, for having them not visible)*
2. Added "onload" attribute to the body that triggers the funciton that changes visibility between pictures.

This way the page waits for them to get loaded and just then starts the functionality.

```
`function visualize()
{
    $('.loading').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.blanket').fadeIn(1000);
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $('.i'+fileIdx).show();
        $('.i'+filePrevIdx).hide();
        filePrevIdx = fileIdx;
        fileIdx = addCyclic(fileIdx);
    }, 290);
}`

`<body style="background-color: black;" onload="visualize()">
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "blanket" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="loading">
            Loading...
        </div>
        <img class="i1" src="./images/1.png" style="display: none;">
        <img class="i2" src="./images/2.png" style="display: none;">
        <img class="i3" src="./images/3.png" style="display: none;">
        <img class="i4" src="./images/4.png" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</body>`
```